# 'Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation ...' - for every method that i call

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, soap

I am trying to create very simple client application for our Polish auction service called Allegro. They provide API in SOAP architecture. The problem is that, every time I try to call any of the methods, I receive:

> Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'name of method'

I am new to web services in general so I have no idea how to find the source of the problem. I am absolutely sure that I am passing correct arguments to the method in the example below:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string ALLEGRO_KEY = "******";
        AllegroWebAPI.AllegroWebApiPortTypeClient allegro = new AllegroWebApiPortTypeClient();
        long version = 0;
        String versionStr = allegro.doQuerySysStatus(out version, 1, 1, ALLEGRO_KEY);

    }
}
```

I am using .NET 4.0 in Visual Studio 2010. I know that there are many people using this API with .NET, even Allegro itself has official Windows Phone 7 client that uses this API. How can I troubleshoot that?

Here is the WSDL address:

https://webapi.allegro.pl/uploader.php?wsdl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have had similiar problem. See your inner exception. I resolved it by extending the size of readerQuotas in web.config :)

Comment: Thank you, binarytree -- this was my solution as well! I noticed that via Fiddler, the size of my Body was 15,515, which was more than my maxStringContentLength. I doubled it from 8192 and 16384, and problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like there is something in the response message from the Web Service which WCF is having difficulty understanding.

Configure [WCF Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) with both service and message tracing enabled. This should give you the actual response message from the web service and will also give you more detailed error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue here. Needed to update service reference after one of its dependencies was changed.