# Webservices: Error in deserializing body of reply message

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, xsd

Using Visual Studio 2010, I'm calling SOAP webservices and keep getting the error "**Error in deserializing body of reply message**".

I call the WS method like this:

```
    wsConfig.config_pttClient client = new wsConfig.config_pttClient();
    wsConfig.getConfigInput gci = new wsConfig.getConfigInput();
    wsConfig.getConfigOutput gco = new wsConfig.getConfigOutput();

    gco = client.getConfig(gci); // the exception is thrown here
```

The method doesn't need input data: I test it using SoapUI and it works fine. Using fiddler, I see the call is made and the answer with all the data correct.

After researching for a while, I tried to alter the `readerQuotas` like `maxStringContentLength`, `maxDepth` etc. inside the `xsd` but no luck.

I got a little workaround for the `getConfig` method though: when I alter the `Reference.cs` file and change the `System.DateTime` variable types to `string`, it works fine but then I need to invoke a `setConfig` method, and that alteration brings [another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935922/accessors-get-and-set-distinct-data-types)... Also, I've read that altering the webservice contract isn't a good practice.

I've been looking for a solution for a while now and here are some places I checked: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225735/error-in-deserializing-body-of-request-message-for-operation), [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f63ae54c-1540-4534-8800-cce986f10894/error-in-deserializing-body-of-reply-message-for-operation?forum=wcf), [this](http://tgynther.blogspot.pt/2010/03/error-in-deserializing-body-of-reply.html) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259778/error-in-deserializing-body-of-reply-message-for-operation-for-every-met).

Can someone help?
Thanks

Comment: What is going over the wire (per [WCF tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx))?

Comment: @RowlandShaw, I'm pretty sure it has to do with date types - here's the first line of my trace file: `em System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ToDateTime(String value)`

Comment: So what is going over the wire?

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: When using the WCF Tracing, you can log out the messages as sent and as received "over the wire" - this allows you to see if the remote web service is breaking its contract by ending data in the wrong format, returning an error message, returning content that is not correctly escaped for XML, etc. - it will help to understand *why* it cannot deserialise the reply.

Comment: Well, it's a file with a huge amount of lines in it, I don't even know where to start looking. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I found a workaround for the problem:

in my `reference.cs` file under the service reference, I changed every `DateTime` and `System.Nullable<System.DateTime>` object to `string` ones - as I had tried before - being this way able to make the `get` method.

When trying to call the `set` method, I pass the dates with this:

```
vt.beginDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("o");
```

The `ToString("o")` seems to be the working solution in order to prevent serialization issues.

Comment: well, this seems not a good solution as reference.cs would be generated again after each service update